# Usage: “condolences with” or “condolences to”

Tags: prepositions

There was an accident and few people died in the accident.

I want to write:

> My condolences with/to the people. (i.e. the people who died)

Which preposition should I use *with* or *to* for this situation?

Comment: (I offer) my condolences to the people.

Comment: You condole (share sadness)  with the _families_ of the deceased. However, you offer or send condolences _to_ the bereaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding [Kate Bunting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866/kate-bunting)'s comment as answer.

> You condole (share sadness) with the families of the deceased. However, you offer or send condolences to the bereaved.